# Converting an slice of strings that represent JSON to JSON and responding to a request

Tags: json, go

I have a slice of strings ([]string) and would like to convert it to JSON.

Here is what my slice looks like when I `fmt.Println()`

```
[
    {\"field1\": \"data1\",  \"field2\": \"data2\"},
    {\"secondField1\": \"data1\",  \"secondfield2\": \"data2\"}
]
```

---

**EDIT**

I want to send it as a response to a HTTP request.

Here is my code.

```
jsonString := `"{"field1": "data1",  "field2": "data2"}",
               "{"secondField1": "data1",  "secondfield2": "data2"}"`

json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(jsonString)
```

w is a `http.ResponseWriter`

---

**ANSWER**

mkopriva has commented on the original question and his solution worked.

Here is the link he provided.

https://play.golang.org/p/n5b5ec4297K

Here is the code that worked for me (you can find it in the playground link)

```
    jsonArray := make([]json.RawMessage, len(stringSlice))

    for i := range stringSlice {
        jsonArray[i] = json.RawMessage(stringSlice[i])
    }

    if err := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(jsonArray); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Comment: so each element in the slice represents a json sting? you'll want to have a look at the [json](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) package; there's plenty of tutorials on the net how to make use of it.

Comment: Yes, each element in the slice represents a JSON string. I've looked at tutorials and the documentation for the JSON package. Can you specify a function or tutorial that would apply to this?

Comment: Your first excerpt looks like it was hand edited (for example : the second "\" in `\"data\2"` escapes the `2` instead of escaping the `"`), and doesn't explain what is stored inside your variable. Can you set up a complete and running example on the [go playground](https://play.golang.org/) to better explain what your input is ?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/n5b5ec4297K

Comment: Add your answer as an answer and remove it from the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

mkopriva has commented on the original question and his solution worked.

Here is the link he provided.

https://play.golang.org/p/n5b5ec4297K

Here is the code that worked for me (you can find it in the playground link)

```
    jsonArray := make([]json.RawMessage, len(stringSlice))

    for i := range stringSlice {
        jsonArray[i] = json.RawMessage(stringSlice[i])
    }

    if err := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(jsonArray); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you want to write the json on a `http.ResponseWriter`. In that case I would suggest an approach like this:

```
func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   myslice := []string{"", "", ""}
   data, err := json.Marshal(myslice)
   if err != nil {
       log.Println("could not marshal", err)
       return
   }
   w.Write(data)
}
```

*Please note that the error handling is not so nice here, and perhaps you would need to add something about content-type to the header, but that is beyond this example.*